# 404s due to [GPT_URL] at the end of URL

Tags: 404

I get a lot of 404s on several of my wordpress posts. All the 404 links have `[GPT_URL]` at the end.

Examples:

- `www.example.com/post-1/[GPT-URL]`
- `www.example.com/post-2/[GPT-URL]`
- `www.example.com/post-3/[GPT-URL]`

Without the string `[GPT_URL]` at the end all my links are valid.  Not sure what is adding this string at the end. Any suggestions on how I could troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'm gonna take a stab that you're either using a faulty wordpress plugin in relation to posting information, or you're using a PHP version incompatible with your wordpress setup.

Comment: Where are these URLs coming from?

Comment: from my own site.

Answer (score 2):

You probably mis-configured some of you ads. GPT stands for "Google Publisher Tag".

There are some fallback tags that are marked up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[GPT_URL]"></script>
```

If you forgot to fill out the `[GPT_URL]`, a browser thinks its a relative URL and so you get your missing URLs.

Comment: I am lost on how to troubleshoot this and find out where it is coming from. Is this something that is misconfigured in DFP (I use google DFP) or on my side in the WP files?